# Finding similarities between users

Tags: r, correlation, mathematical-statistics, similarities

In my current context I have a data Set with 5 users and 19 questions
The questions are binary True (Positive) or False (Negative) and are graded from 1-100 so a +90 means 90% True (but it does not mean 10% False
I would like to find a similarity score between each user to understand how similar the users are in their way to answer the questionnaire.

I tried to use a Pearson Correlation score but it I think it does not make sense two people can be highly correlated (r= 97%) but not similar at all for example (User 1(V1) and User 2(V2).

What is the best way to find a similarity score between users in my sitution ?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your description of the dataset. You say the questions are binary, but are graded 1 to 100. If they're binary, they should only have two possible scores apiece, not 100. Furthermore, if a 90 means 90% true, why doesn't it also mean 10% false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd treat a user's list of 19 grades as a vector and compute the cosine between vectors. Thus you'll get a figure between -1 and 1; and in the case you mention, namely the first 2 columns, it looks like you would get a cosine close to -1 (close to colinear, but pointing in different directions).
The formula for the cosine between 2 vectors u and v in any number of dimensions is $${{u . v} \over {|u|^2 |v^2|}}$$